# Fluent api Cascade delete on relationships to one table

Tags: c#, ef-fluent-api

I have the following configuration. I have a User. The user has a postal Address and a Physical Address (see below).

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public Guid UserProfileId {get; set;}

    public Guid PostalAddressId {get;set;}
    public virtual Address PostalAddress {get;set;}

    public Guid PhysicalAddressId {get;set;}
    public virtual Address PhysicalAddress {get;set;}
}

public class Address{
    public Guid AddressId {get;set;}
    public string LineOne {get;set;}
    public string LineTwo {get;set;}
    public string LineThree {get;set;}
}
```

Next is my fluent mapping

```
public UserProfileMapping()
{
    ToTable("UserProfile");
    HasKey(pk => pk.UserProfileId);
    Property(pr => pr.UserProfileId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

    HasRequired(a => a.PostalAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(fk => fk.PostalAddressId);
    HasRequired(a => a.PhysicalAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(fk => fk.PhysicalAddressId);
}

public AddressMapping()
{
    ToTable("Address");
    HasKey(pk => pk.AddressId);
    Property(pr => pr.AddressId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}
```

When i try to run update-database i get:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.UserProfile_dbo.Address_PhysicalAddressId' on table
>   'UserProfile' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.

I am required to not have any reverse mapping on the Address object.
I also need to be able to hard delete the UserProfile object including its children addresses (of which there will only be two of in the address table).

My question is, Is what I want possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]
The Address object is also used in objects such as UserCompany and Customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the addresses are not UserProfile's children, but just association, you don't want to use cascade deletion :

```
HasRequired(a => a.PostalAdress)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.PostalAddressId)
    .WillCascadeDelete(false);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't give enough information. The Address object can belong to more than just a UserProfile. a Company Object can also have an address and a Customer can also have an address. from my understanding this would not work using your suggested answer because the one to one mapping. i can update my question to reflect this.

Comment: How can you delete the userProfile including its children addresses if the adresses can be linked to other object?

Comment: You don't want cascade deletion if the adress is not owned by the UserProfile.

Comment: So an address will either belong to a customer, or a User or a Company. After giving this some thought I think I designed the tables wrong. 
Originally I was going to have UserPhysicalAddress, UserPostalAddress, CompanyAddress and CustomerAddress, but because they all had the same model structure I decided to make a single Address model. Implementing this has become a headache.